# How to gain sudo access after powerwashing (factory resetting) my computer?

Tags: sudo, chrome-book

I just powerwashed (that's a factory reset on chromebooks) my computer so that it would be be 'brand new,' however now I don't have sudo access anymore. I used to not need a password to use sudo, however now a password is required and I have no idea what it is. I tried my login password, however that didn't work. Any advice?

Comment: Is this a chromebook?  according to https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183084?hl=en "powerwash" is google-speak for "factory reset" and the user you login with after "powerwashing" will be the device's "owner" (i presume that includes sudo privs)

Comment: Yes I am talking about chromebooks. I just added the tag 'chrome-book' Thanks for the suggestion. @Mat

Comment: @cas Yes I would think the same, however I am unable to access sudo.

Comment: If you've just powerwashed it, you've got no local data to lose.  You may as well enable Developer Mode.  As described here http://www.howtogeek.com/210817/how-to-enable-developer-mode-on-your-chromebook/ part of this procedure is setting the root password.  I'm no expert on chromebooks, and don't own one, so that's about as much as i know on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE: I wrote this before the "chromebook" tag was added.  These instructions are applicable to Linux systems; I have no idea what Chromebook is like or if these instructions will work on Chrome OS.**

First, try logging out and logging in as `root` using your own password.  It may not work, but if so you've got it handled easily.  The point here is that root access, or having the root password, is *not* the same as having `sudo` privileges.  `sudo` must be configured before it will work.

If you can't log in as root, the fastest method of handling I know if is to reboot in single user mode.  (`root` is the "single user".)  To do this, reboot and look for a message something like "press any key to enter the menu..."  Then press a key to enter GRUB.

You don't need to arrow up or down to choose a different entry in the GRUB list; the selected one will do.  Press `e` to edit the entry.  That will bring you to another list; on my CentOS VM I have 3 lines, which start with `root`, `kernel` and `initrd` respectively.  Arrow key to the `kernel` line, press `e` to edit, **add a space followed by a `1` at the end of the line you are editing**, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept changes, and then press `b` to boot.

The system will come up in single user mode; you will get a bash prompt with a # sign.  You are now logged in as root!

To change the root password so you will know what it is from here on out, type `passwd` and follow the prompts to enter your new root password (twice).

**To set yourself up to run `sudo` in the future:** type `less /etc/sudoers` and verify that it includes the line `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` (the # is not a comment for this line).  It will probably be at the bottom of the file.

Then, add a file named `elsie` to `/etc/sudoers.d` with the contents

```
elsie ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

(assuming `elsie` is your user name.)  I recommend leaving out the NOPASSWD part for security consciousness and instead using the line `elsie ALL=(ALL) ALL`, but that's your decision.  You can do this most easily by typing:

```
echo 'elsie ALL=(ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers.d/elsie
```

Then simply reboot as usual.  You will have `sudo` access, and you now also know the `root` password for future use.

Comment: My chromebook is a linux device. Thanks for the help. I am just wondering how to install grub, or is grub something that comes with all linux devices?

Comment: GRUB is "GRand Unified Bootloader".  It is not Linux; it is what *loads* Linux.  The boot sequence is BIOS (or UEFI on many newer systems) -> GRUB (or other bootloader, but GRUB is most common) -> Linux.  The usual way to bring up single user mode is by running `sudo init 1`, but since you don't have sudo access you can't do that.  So, you need to use options at boot time to change the root password.  If you don't have any GRUB menu show up during boot, try using a recovery disk, if you have one.

Comment: A chromebook runs the linux kernel but is otherwise not very much like a "normal" linux machine.  That's why some people go to the trouble of installing a traditional linux like ubuntu or debian or fedora on chromebooks.

Comment: @Wildcard I'll try rebooting. When would I click any key?

Comment: @ElsieReynolds, on my Linux machines it's a few seconds after you press the "power on" button (or after the machine fully shuts down, if rebooting).  The message is displayed for only a few seconds before the boot process continues.  And, on my machine at least, there are two separate messages.  The first is from Lenovo, the manufacturers of my laptop; that says to press 'Enter' to change the settings, but it refers to BIOS settings—not what you need.  The second is from GRUB and says to press any key to enter the menu.  I really don't know what options you'll see on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

On a chromebook and after a powerwash:

You can gain access to the VT2 shell by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>⮕</kbd> and you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>⬅</kbd> to get back to your regular screen. The right-arrow is <kbd>F2</kbd> and the left-arrow is <kbd>F1</kbd>.

> Once you have the login prompt, you should see a set of instructions telling you about command-line access. By default, you can login as the `chronos` user with no password. This includes the ability to do password-less sudo. The instructions on the screen will tell you how you can set a password. They also tell you how to disable screen dimming.

[chromium.googlesource.com chromiumos docs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/developer_mode.md#vt2)

Once you are signed in, you can run the following command to set a password so that you can run `sudo` from the browser shell:

```
sudo chromeos-setdevpasswd
```

However, you won't have the ability to alter system files. In order to alter system files, you need to run the following command:

```
sudo ./make_dev_ssd.sh --remove_rootfs_verification --partitions 2
```

Alternatively, you can set a root password and enable write access by powerwashing to developer mode using the power-button+<kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>⮕</kbd> and then you see a screen with a warning and there is highlighted line that mentions enabling write access. Click this line and set a password and then the system will reboot.

Later, after you boot back up, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>⮕</kbd> and use the password you set to login as `root`.

Then, run the following command to enable the password for root and sudo:

```
sudo chromeos-setdevpasswd
```

Here, you will be prompted to set your password or you can use the same password as before and you will have write access to system files with `sudo`.